# Table center alignment doesn't seem to work

Tags: tables, longtable

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb] 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{center}  

\caption{ Hydrostatics of 3b Asymmetric Catamaran Model [{s/L} 0.3]}\label{tab1}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}    \hline
\textbf {Parameter} & \textbf {Catamaran}   & \textbf {Inboard Catamaran} & \textbf {Outboard Catamaran} & \textbf {Units}\\ \hline
Displacement &  349705 &    349705 &    349705  & Kg\\\hline
Draft Amidships &       2.457&      2.457&      2.457   &   m  \\ \hline
Wetted Surface Area &   499.612 &   499.612 &   499.612&    \(m^2\)\\ \hline
\(C{_B}\)   &0.432 &    0.432 & 0.432 & - \\ \hline
L/B &5.239 &    5.239 & 5.239&  - \\ \hline
B/T &   2.471&  2.471 & 2.471 & - \\ \hline
\(L/\Delta ^ {1/3}\)    & 5.395 &   5.395   &5.395 &    - \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \end{center}

\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

[image: my last column is out of alignment]

Comment: The table is wider than the text width.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: A general question: Why does you table repeat the same numeric data three times?

Answer (score 4):

See, if the following form of table is acceptable to you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \centering
\caption{Hydrostatics of 3b Asymmetric Catamaran Model [{s/L} 0.3]}
    \label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{3}{S[table-format=3.3]|}c|}    \hline
\thead[b]{Parameter}& {\thead[b]{Catamaran}}
                                & {\thead[b]{Inboard\\ Catamaran}} 
                & {\thead[b]{Outboard\\ Catamaran}}     & \thead {Units}\\  \hline
Displacement        &  349.705  &  349.705  & 349.705   & t             \\  \hline
Draft Amidships     &  2.457    &  2.457    & 2.457     & m             \\  \hline
Wetted Surface Area &  499.612  &  499.612  &   499.612 & \si{m^2}      \\  \hline
\(C{_B}\)           &  0.432    &  0.432    & 0.432     & --            \\  \hline
L/B                 &  5.239    &  5.239    & 5.239     & --            \\  \hline
B/T                 &  2.471    &  2.471    & 2.471     & --            \\  \hline
\(L/\Delta^{1/3}\)  & 5.395     &  5.395    & 5.395     & --            \\  \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have used `\si{m^2}` in the last column. Are you sure there should  be dot in the  2nd row?

Comment: I just notice this, now is corrected.

Comment: For better formatting I change units from kg to tonne ...

Comment: I would change `table-format=6.3` to `table-format=3.3`.

Comment: @ Mico, I correct table with as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the table is too wide. You can get a reasonable width by splitting the long headers.

I also suggest to avoid vertical rules. You can easily reinsert them, though, from the code below.

Some more notes.

1. Don't use `center`, which adds unwanted vertical space.
2. Be consistent with the use of math mode in the first column.
3. For numeric tables, it's recommended to use `siunitx`.
4. Units should be typeset in the format required by the International System. For instance, the symbol for the kilogram is kg, not Kg.
5. An en-dash should be used for a missing value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,makecell}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htb] 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\centering

\caption{Hydrostatics of 3b Asymmetric Catamaran Model [\(s/L\ 0.3\)]}\label{tab1}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
\thead{Parameter} &
{\thead{Catamaran}} &
{\thead{Inboard \\ Catamaran}} &
{\thead{Outboard \\ Catamaran}} &
\thead {Units}\\
\midrule
Displacement        & \num{349705} & \num{349705} & \num{349705} & \si{\kg}  \\
Draft Amidships     &     2.457    &     2.457    &     2.457    & \si{\m}   \\
Wetted Surface Area &   499.612    &   499.612    &   499.612    & \si{\m^2} \\
\(C_B\)             &     0.432    &     0.432    &     0.432    & --        \\
\(L/B\)             &     5.239    &     5.239    &     5.239    & --        \\
\(B/T\)             &     2.471    &     2.471    &     2.471    & --        \\
\(L/\Delta^{1/3}\)  &     5.395    &     5.395    &     5.395    & --        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should "Parameter" maybe be left-aligned?

Comment: @Mico Possibly, at the OP's choice

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions (several of which are also made in the other answers):

- reorganize the header to as to eliminate repeated information from individual cells; instead, group the information and present a clear hierarchy of information. This will automatically lead to a more compact (and more readable) presentation of the material
- with the header clearly organized, there's **no longer a need to provide boldface** -- do avoid the risk of coming across as **shouting** at your readers
- align the numbers on the respective decimal markers
- change units of first row (displacement) from kilograms to tonnes, so as to make the numbers occupy a more similar range
- give the table a more open "look" by not using any vertical lines and fewer, but well spaced, horizontal lines. To get well-spaced horizontal lines, use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb] 
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} % optional
\sisetup{table-format=3.3,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=3} % change to "2" if desired
\centering 
\caption{ Hydrostatics of 3b Asymmetric Catamaran Model [{s/L} 0.3]}\label{tab1}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l SSS l @{}}  
\toprule  
Parameter & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Catamaran Model} & Units \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
& {Basic} & {Inboard} & {Outboard} \\ 
\midrule
Displacement    & 349.705 & 349.705 & 349.705 & $10^3$\,\si{\kilo\gram}\\
Draft Amidships &   2.457 &   2.457 &   2.457 &  \si{\meter} \\ 
Wetted Surface Area& 499.612&499.612& 499.612 & \si{\meter\squared}\\
\(C_B\)         &   0.432 &   0.432 &   0.432 & -- \\
\(L/B\)         &   5.239 &   5.239 &   5.239 & -- \\
\(B/T\)         &   2.471 &   2.471 &   2.471 & -- \\
\(L/\Delta^{1/3}\) &5.395 &   5.395 &   5.395 & -- \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```